# Scrollview - TextView - what is the best technique of scrolling

Tags: android, scroll, textview, scrollview

My app is logging a text information and the technique I use is based on a TextView, embedded in a ScrollView, that contains the complete string.

The real drawback of this method is that the string becomes horribly large over time and the best that you can experience is a slowdown on the performance if not a crash because the system is outOfMemory.

What are the other techniques I could use?

Here is the code I've come up with:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    boolean run = true;
    String str = "", t;
    int i = 0;
    TextView txt;
    ScrollView sv;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        sv = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.sv);

        t = "this is the log for monday the 24th of july 2017 - number ";


        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                start();
            }
        });

    }

    private void start(){
        new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        i++;
                        str = str + t + i + "\n";
                        txt.setText(str);
                        sv.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 0, 100);
    }
}
```

and the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.narb.log.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Start"
        />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/sv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/btn"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="This is the log number"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            />
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of *str=str+t+i+"\n";* and *txt.setText(str);* 
Try using *str=t+i+"\n";* and *txt.setText(txt.getText()+str);*
OR you can also simply use *txt.setText(txt.getText()+t+i+"\n");*